# Finder Sync extension: cannot communicate through UNIX domain socket

Tags: sockets, cocoa, ipc, finder, appstore-sandbox

I have the following problem: I'm implementing the Finder Sync plugin, which needs to communicate with main application. Previously, when I used old good mach_inject, that worked fine via the UNIX domain socket.
However, now, even allowed com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write, and com.apple.security.network.client, I cannot connect to socket, always receiving `9/17/15 11:15:34.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: finderplugin(660) deny network-outbound /Users/nickolay/Library/blablabla/.cmdsckt`

Anybody has any ideas how to fix this? Maybe, other entitlements, or other socket path is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, NSXPCConnection doesn't seem to work, so I ended up in using mach ports. I.e. NSMachPort, NSMachBootstrapServer and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add below contents in your extension's entitlements.

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl</key>
<array>
    <string>(allow network-outbound)</string>
    <string>(allow network-bind)</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please specify where did you get this information? It doesn't seem to exist in App Sandbox documentation on Apple's site (or I somehow mislooked it?).

Comment: Even I tried a many ways to establish a communication and finally I found from Ashutosh Mehra's tweet about APP sandbox, which is undocumented in Apple's site.
[His Tweet](https://twitter.com/ashutoshmehra/status/201750727197065216)

Comment: Thank you, that's very valuable and interesting post. However Apple can remove that .sbpl extensions at any time (but it still exists in El Capitan).